# How to pick out columns of a matrix with specified step

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix A with 500 rows and 1024 columns. I would like to generate a matrix consisting of evenly spaced columns from A, say with step size 2^5. How do I do this in Numpy? I haven't seen this explained in the references I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use slicing:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.rand(512,1024)
step_size = 2 ** 5
arr[:, ::step_size]  # shape is (512, 32)
```

So what it does is keeping all the rows, while taking all the columns with the desired step size. You can read about numpy indexing in the following link:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html?highlight=indexing#other-indexing-options

You can apply the same logic to the rows or to both rows and columns to get a more sophisticated slicing.